# Postgres function that takes in an interval and returns a result set

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to be able to create a function that takes in a "standardized" queryset that has an integer id field and a timestamp as the columns and then modify the queryset to aggregate by count for the number that are in each 30 min block.  The code below works for 30 min blocks if you replace the Q with a real query and do a WITH (QUERY) Q.  But I want to be able to pass in any query that fits the type and then get back the new SETOF range_durations_type.

```
CREATE TYPE range_durations_type AS (dtime TIMESTAMP, counts BIGINT);
CREATE TYPE object_datetime AS (id INTEGER, dtime TIMESTAMP);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION time_range_durations(Q range_durations_type, start_date TIMESTAMP, end_date TIMESTAMP)
  RETURNS SETOF range_durations_type AS $$
BEGIN

  RETURN QUERY WITH q_cleaned AS (
    SELECT
      Q.id,
      Q.dtime,
      Q.dtime - (
                  (extract(EPOCH FROM Q.dtime :: TIMESTAMP)) :: INTEGER -
                  extract(EPOCH FROM Q.dtime :: TIMESTAMP) :: INTEGER / 1800 * 1800
                ) * INTERVAL '1 second' AS rounded_dtime
    FROM Q
  )
               SELECT
                 series.dtime,
                 count(q_cleaned.id)
               FROM (
                      SELECT
                        *
                      FROM
                        generate_series(start_date, end_date, '30 minutes') dtime) series
                 LEFT JOIN q_cleaned ON series.dtime = q_cleaned.rounded_dtime
               GROUP BY 1
               ORDER BY 1;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: OT, but... you're aware that Postgres has range types, right? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html

Comment: Yes, I've been going through the types to see if any of them would work.  I'm just not familiar enough with them... Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

I think a complete solution is going to be beyond a single answer here, but there are several important pieces I would recommend looking at directly.

1. Range types.  It seems to me you are looking for a set of intervals.  This would allow you to do something like:

   ```
     CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION time_range_durations(bounds rsrange, inc interval)
   ```

   And this would allow you to do something very different, namely a range, and an interval that could be used to increment within it.  So you could look at things within two timestamps by an arbitrary increment.
2. You could then pass in inc to your generate_series function.